# Mapping datasets to NoSql (MongoDB) collection

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

## what I have ?

I have data of  'n' department 
each department has more than 1000 datasets
each datasets has more than 10,000 csv files(size greater than 10MB) each with different schema.

This data even grow more in future

## What I want to DO?

I want to map this data into mongodb

## What approaches I used?

I can't map each datasets to a document in mongo since it has limit of 4-16MB

I cannot create collection for each datasets as max number of collection is also limited (<24000)

So finally I thought to create collection for each department , in that collection one document for each record in csv file belonging to that department.

## I want to know from you :

will there be a performance issue if we map each record to document?

is there any max limit for number of documents?

is there any other design i can do?

Comment: There is no limit for collection size in MongoDB, [unless it is capped collection.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**will there be a performance issue if we map each record to document?**

mapping each record to document in mongodb is not a bad design. You can have a look at FAQ at mongodb site
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#do-mongodb-databases-have-tables . 
It says,

> ...Instead of tables, a MongoDB database stores its data in collections,
>   which are the rough equivalent of RDBMS tables. A collection holds **one
>   or more documents, which corresponds to a record** or a row in a
>   relational database table....

Along with limitation of BSON document size(16MB), It also has max limit of 100 for level of document nesting

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON Document Size

> ...Nested Depth for BSON Documents Changed in version 2.2.
>
> MongoDB supports **no more than 100 levels** of nesting for BSON document...

So its better to go with one document for each record

**is there any max limit for number of documents?**

No, Its mention in reference manual of mongoDB

> ...Maximum Number of Documents in a Capped Collection Changed in
>   version
>   2.4.
>
> If you specify a maximum number of documents for a capped collection
>   using the max parameter to create, the limit must be less than 232
>   documents. If you do not specify a maximum number of documents when
>   creating a capped collection, **there is no limit on the number of
>   documents** ...

**is there any other design i can do?**

If your document is too large then you can think of document partitioning at application level. But it will have high computation requirement at application layer.

Answer (score 0):

> will there be a performance issue if we map each record to document?

That depends entirely on how you search them. When you use a lot of queries which affect only one document, it is likely even faster that way. When a higher document-granularity results in a lot of document-spanning queries, it will get slower because MongoDB can't do that itself.

> is there any max limit for number of documents?

No.

> is there any other design i can do?

Maybe, but that depends on how you want to query your data. When you are content with treating files as a BLOB which is retrieved as a whole but not searched or analyzed on the database level, you could consider storing them on [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/). It's a way to store files larger than 16MB on MongoDB.

In General, MongoDB database design doesn't depend so much on what and how much data you have, but rather on how you want to work with it.